# Google Font in Android Studio Application?

Tags: android-studio, google-font-api

I am trying to use a font from the available online Google Fonts (https://www.google.com/fonts). I would like to put the font in my Android Studio app so that the text looks nice rather than boring. Thanks.

Comment: As stated you will need to download the fonts which you can do. The info on the page says "To download fonts, simply create a selection of fonts, open the drawer at the bottom of the screen, then click the "Download" icon in the upper-right corner of the selection drawer. You can download the fonts to use in mock-ups, documents, or locally on your machine."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-custom-fonts-in-your-android-apps.html

I believe you have to use a .ttf font file.